# Toggle class name

Tags: javascript, css

I've got a list of items:

```
<ul id='list'>
    <li id='1-i' class='visible'><a href='javascript:return false;' onclick="toggle_class('1-i');">Toggle #1</a></li>
    <li id='2-i' class='visible'><a href='javascript:return false;' onclick="toggle_class('2-i');">Toggle #2</a></li>
    <li id='3-i' class='visible'><a href='javascript:return false;' onclick="toggle_class('3-i');">Toggle #3</a></li>
    <li id='4-i' class='visible'><a href='javascript:return false;' onclick="toggle_class('4-i');">Toggle #4</a></li>
</ul>
```

1. If you click one of the items (i.e. "Toggle #1"), I want the class name of all other items to change from *visible* to *invisible*.
2. If you click another item now, I want the class name of this item to change to *visible* (with no effect to all other class names, they should remain as they are)

Simple example: You first clicked "Toggle #4", then "Toggle #1". Result should be:

```
<ul id='list'>
    <li id='1-i' class='visible'><a href='javascript:return false;' onclick="toggle_class('1-i');">Toggle #1</a></li>
    <li id='2-i' class='invisible'><a href='javascript:return false;' onclick="toggle_class('2-i');">Toggle #2</a></li>
    <li id='3-i' class='invisible'><a href='javascript:return false;' onclick="toggle_class('3-i');">Toggle #3</a></li>
    <li id='4-i' class='visible'><a href='javascript:return false;' onclick="toggle_class('4-i');">Toggle #4</a></li>
</ul>
```

I tried to write a js function but the behavior is different from what I expected:

```
        var firstrun = true;

        function toggle_class(id) {
            var thisElem = document.getElementById(id);
            var invisible = "invisible";
            var visible = "visible";
            if (thisElem.className == 'invisible' && !firstrun) {
                thisElem.className = thisElem.className.replace(invisible, visible);
            } else {
                thisElem.className = thisElem.className.replace(visible, invisible);
            }
            if (firstrun) {
                var children = document.getElementsByClassName('visible');
                for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                    if (children[i].id != id) {
                        children[i].className = thisElem.className.replace(visible, invisible);
                    }
                }
            }
            firstrun = false;
        }
```

On first click, the selected item changes its class to *invisible*, and so does every second item in the list. I don't understand why this happens. What do I need to change in the code to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that on your first run, you gather all the elements on the page with class visible and change it to invisible including your first element

```
 if (thisElem.className == 'invisible') {
    thisElem.className = thisElem.className.replace(invisible, visible);
 } else if(!firstrun) {
    thisElem.className = thisElem.className.replace(visible, invisible);
 }
```

might be better since you need to make sure that the element doesn't get changed to invisible. But that would leave the second if block to continue running. It might be prudent to do this instead

```
if(!firstrun){
    if (thisElem.className == 'invisible') {
        thisElem.className = thisElem.className.replace(invisible, visible);
    } else {
       thisElem.className = thisElem.className.replace(visible, invisible);
    }
}
else{
    var children = document.getElementsByClassName('visible');
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
       if (children[i].id != id) {
          children[i].className = thisElem.className.replace(visible, invisible);
       }
    }
}
```

I kinda am wondering why you're using variables for strings like var invisible = "invisible" since its only used once and thats just as long and wordy as just typing the string itself. if you're going to set a variable might as well use it more than once with it. also no need to use replace unless there are more classes that might get added but that's just imo. and it shouldn't affect the code

Answer (score 0):

Using your code as base (I've only got it working really, no optimizations):

```js
var firstrun = true;

function toggle_class(id) {  
    var thisElem = document.getElementById(id);
    var invisible = "invisible";
    var visible = "visible";
    if (thisElem.className == 'invisible' && !firstrun) {
        thisElem.className = thisElem.className.replace(invisible, visible);
        thisElem.childNodes[2].innerHTML = thisElem.className; //Added for extra visibility
    } else if (thisElem.className == 'visible' && !firstrun) {
        thisElem.className = thisElem.className.replace(visible, invisible);
        thisElem.childNodes[2].innerHTML = thisElem.className; //Added for extra visibility
    }
    if (firstrun) {
        var children = document.getElementById('list').children;
        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            if (children[i].getAttribute('id') != id && children[i].className != invisible) {
                children[i].className = invisible;
            }
            children[i].childNodes[2].innerHTML = children[i].className; //Added for extra visibility
        }
    }
    firstrun = false;
    return false;
}
```

```html
<ul id='list'>
  <li id='1-i' class="visible"><a href="#" onclick="toggle_class('1-i');">Toggle #1</a>  <span id='1-is'></span></li>
  <li id='2-i' class="visible"><a href="#" onclick="toggle_class('2-i');">Toggle #2</a>  <span id='2-is'></span></li>
  <li id='3-i' class="visible"><a href="#" onclick="toggle_class('3-i');">Toggle #3</a>  <span id='3-is'></span></li>
  <li id='4-i' class="visible"><a href="#" onclick="toggle_class('4-i');">Toggle #4</a>  <span id='4-is'></span></li>
</ul>
```

The code is perhaps not optimal as it uses inline events, not needed variables and easy to break logic. But it works (now at least)! It's important to understand the code you write, but also how you can improve on it.

There are other responses that use more optimized code (well, one anyway from @boombox). Learn from that. There is no need to go to jQuery just for this though, but if you use a lot of javascript it might be an idea as it makes life simpler.

*Also, I removed your `href=return false` and put the return statement in the function instead. It was causing console errors for me.*

Answer (score 0):

I fixed and cleaned up your code below. It should be a lot simpler and easier to understand.

**JavaScript:**

```
var liElements = document.getElementById('list').children,
    notClickedYet = true;

// attach a click listener to each list element
Array.prototype.forEach.call(liElements, function (element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        var li = e.target.parentNode;

        // run this the first time around
        if (notClickedYet) {
            notClickedYet = false;
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(liElements, function (ele) {
                ele.className = 'invisible';
            });
        }

        // run this every time
        li.className = li.className === 'invisible' ? 'visible' : 'invisible';
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul id='list'>
    <li id='1-i' class='visible'><a href='#'>Toggle #1</a></li>
    <li id='2-i' class='visible'><a href='#'>Toggle #2</a></li>
    <li id='3-i' class='visible'><a href='#'>Toggle #3</a></li>
    <li id='4-i' class='visible'><a href='#'>Toggle #4</a></li>
</ul>
```

See this working **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bqgc55eg/1/)**.

Answer (score -1):

I think this might work (jquery):

```
<ul id='list' class="first-run">
...
</ul>

$('#list > li').on('click', function() {
  $('.first-run > li').toggleClass('visible invisible');
  $('.first-run').removeClass('first-run');
  $(this).toggleClass('visible invisible');
  return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jyes174k/

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I've done - I added a toggle class to all of the items.
When a toggle is clicked, it adds the invisible class to all of the items except for the one clicked.  Requires jQuery.

HTML

```
<ul id='list'>
    <li id='1-i' class=' toggle'>Toggle #1</li>
    <li id='2-i' class=' toggle'>Toggle #2</li>
    <li id='3-i' class=' toggle'>Toggle #3</li>
    <li id='4-i' class=' toggle'>Toggle #4</li>
</ul>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('.toggle').click(function(){
    $('.toggle').toggleClass('invisible');
    $(this).toggleClass('invisible');
});
```

**Tested and works**, don't know why it got down-voted.

**EDIT** Added a way to show lists again, by making it toggle.  And a [link to a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4dxdbxus/1/).

Comment: A guess as to why it has been downvoted: 1. It uses jQuery, even though the OP mentioned nothing about jQuery. 2. It doesn't work like the OP requested (1st click change all but the clicked, 2nd click change only the clicked element)

Answer (score -1):

Why not use jQuery instead?
http://jsfiddle.net/dyys5yjd/

```
<ul id='list'>
    <li id='1-i' class='visible'><a href='javascript:void(0);'>Toggle #1</a></li>
    <li id='2-i' class='visible'><a href='javascript:void(0);'>Toggle #2</a></li>
    <li id='3-i' class='visible'><a href='javascript:void(0);'>Toggle #3</a></li>
    <li id='4-i' class='visible'><a href='javascript:void(0);'>Toggle #4</a></li>
</ul>

$(document).on('click','.visible',function(){
   $(this).toggle(); 
});
```

Comment: This does not comply with the users request at all. It doesn't toggle all classes on first click. Actually, it doesn't change classes at all (it shows/hides by "display: none").